# im having an issue with my code counting occurring characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm creating a Ruby program that will use "hello world!" as a standard string unless a string is specified, I can get it to register the "hello world" or any string I pass in through IRB but once I get to the calculation method I'm getting method errors and don't know where it's going wrong.

```
def display
  calculateFrequencies
end
private
def calculateFrequencies
  @text = "Hello World!"
  @letters = text.downcase.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |c, letters|
      next if c == " "
      @letters[c] += 1
  end
end
```

the expected output would be for example it calculates the frequency and then when the method display is called then the frequency will be shown in the terminal e.g. `Hello World = h=1 e=2 l=3 o=2 d=1`
but what I am actually getting is this.

```
h.calculateFrequencies
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from LetterHistogram.rb:17:in `block in calculateFrequencies'
from LetterHistogram.rb:15:in `each_char'
from LetterHistogram.rb:15:in `with_object'
from LetterHistogram.rb:15:in `calculateFrequencies'
from (irb):5
from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Why the rush to select the first answer offered? You don't want to see others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the block you're trying to use a non-initialized instance variable `@letters` as it were an initialized hash/array. You either need to initialize it before you call the block or (rather) use the block param.  I'd suggest to try sth like this:

```
def calculateFrequencies
  @text = "Hello World!"
  @letters = @text.downcase.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |c, letters|
      next if c == " "
      letters[c] += 1
  end
end
```

It works in my console:

```
[8] pry(main)> @text = "Hello World!"  
=> "Hello World!"
[9] pry(main)> @letters = @text.downcase.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |c, letters|  
[9] pry(main)*   next if c == " "      
[9] pry(main)*   letters[c] += 1      
[9] pry(main)* end    
=> {"h"=>1, "e"=>1, "l"=>3, "o"=>2, "w"=>1, "r"=>1, "d"=>1, "!"=>1}
```

Comment: To clarify for the OP, what this answer means by “non-initialized” is that `@letters` doesn’t exist inside of the loop. `@letters` is the **return** value of the loop, so it won’t exist until **after** the loop is over.

Comment: the problem still occurs even when using what you have demonstrated there

Comment: See my output. Are you sure you have same code and that you don't have a new error?

Comment: ignore the top comment I misspelt in the terminal, but on the other hand the code works just not to the format i'm after do you know of a way where when I call the display method I can get the whole alphabet to display and it will show a result next to the ones used and leave the others blank

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you mean.

Comment: Your first sentence is glaringly incorrect.If one could not assign a value to an uninitialized instance variable how could it be initialized? The point is that `@letters` has not been initialized when `@letters[c] += 1` is first executed, so the expression becomes `nil[c] += 1`, causing Ruby to raise an exception that `nil` has no method `[]`.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, rephrased it.

Comment: when the method is called how would I go about getting it to go from this {"h"=>1, "e"=>1, "l"=>3, "o"=>2, "w"=>1, "r"=>1, "d"=>1, "!"=>1} to this A: , B: ,C: , D:* , E:* , F: , G: , H:* , I: , J: , K: , L:*** , M: , N: , O:** ,P: ,Q: , R: , S: , T: , U: , V: , W:* , X: , Y: , Z: , and i need to ignore the special characters

Comment: Let's move that to a new question

Comment: ive moved this to another question now